# Is there a thread safe way to create PNG images in pre-4.0 iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, png, ios

I'm pretty sure that

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef])
```

is the cause of random-looking memory leaks when done in a background thread (it causes leaks that trace back to CGContextDrawPDFPage!).

Now, everywhere else on the internet says I should use CGImageDestination, which isn't available until iOS4. Is there any way for me to encode the bitmap as PNG other than importing heavyweight PNG libraries?

EDIT: Now this is interesting. For the whole background thread that creates the PNGs, I drain the autorelease pool every 10 generated PNGs. The memory warnings and the crash disappear after I add an autorelease pool around the saving. Are these calls that memory hungry?

```
NSAutoreleasePool* savePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]);
[imageData writeToFile:savePath atomically:NO];

[savePool drain];
```

Comment: I use UIImageJPGRepresentation (I know its PNG that you're using) in a separate thread quite intensively without any problem.  Are you sure that the problem doesn't come from the imageReg that could be written in another thread ?

Comment: The CGImageRef is generated in the same thread that does the UIImagePNGRepresentation and I'm not sharing it with any other thread.

Comment: Edited the main question: wrapping an autorelease pool around the saving code removes the memory warnings and the crash. It looks like those two lines of code allocate so much memory that you can't keep them unreleased for too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice,

```
UIImageXXXRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef])
```

seems to be thread safe enough. Just look out for mem usage.

Comment: @Bill UIKit functions that draw to graphics contexts have been threadsafe since iOS 4.

Comment: @sobri This is not a drawing function. This is an encoding function. Although these encoding function has no reason to be thread-unsafe, I still cannot find a clue for safety to use this function in background thread. Please let me know if you have one...

Comment: @Eonil I've used it extensively in background threads. It's safe to do, so long as the input data isn't being modified outside of the thread. (Which would be a general threaded programming bug, and not specific to this API).

Comment: @sobri Do you really think your personal experience can be a clue to provide thread safety?

Comment: @Eonil, yes, absolutely, considering the code has been running on tens of thousands of devices. That makes it science, frankly. And even without that, it's clear that the `UIImageXXXRepresentation` functions themselves don't have any reason to not be thread safe. They take input vars, interpret them (not mutate them), and produce output vars. For them to not be thread safe would be a bug.

Comment: @sobri I see your point. Just for the record, I don't agree with you.

Comment: @Eonil If you are experiencing crashes while using these methods in background threads, I recommend you post a question about it, with code samples. These methods are being used in background threads by thousands of apps, for many years, so this is well worn paths. Someone will be able to help you with your specific case.